# Avoid shuffle when joining two tables with same partitions without bucketting strategy

Tags: pyspark, hive, databricks

I have two Hive tables A and B with:

- same partitions (`partition_1`, `partition_2`)
- an extra `id` field that is not sorted in partitions

When I join these two tables in PySpark, for example with:

```py
df_A = spark.table("db.A")
df_B = spark.table("db.B")
df = df_A.join(df_B, how="inner", on=["partition_1", "partition_2", "id"])
```

I always end up with a shuffle:

```
+- == Initial Plan ==
  Project (23)
  +- SortMergeJoin Inner (22)
     :- Sort (18)
     :  +- Exchange (17)
     :     +- Filter (16)
     :        +- Scan parquet db.A (15)
     +- Sort (21)
        +- Exchange (20)
           +- Filter (19)
              +- Scan parquet db.B (7)
```

I created two similar tables but with a bucketting strategy this time:

```py
df.write.partitionBy("partition_A", "partition_B").bucketBy(10, "id").saveAsTable(...)
```

And there is no more shuffle in the join

```
+- == Initial Plan ==
  Project (17)
  +- SortMergeJoin Inner (16)
     :- Sort (13)
     :  +- Filter (12)
     :     +- Scan parquet db.A (11)
     +- Sort (15)
        +- Filter (14)
           +- Scan parquet db.B (5)
```

My questions are:

1. **Can I avoid this shuffle in the join without having to re-create the tables with a bucketting strategy ?**
2. Does this shuffle operate on all data ? Or does it consider that the partitions are the same and optimise this shuffle ?

What I tried so far:

- repartitioning on partitions (`df.repartition("partition_A", "partition_B")`) on both tables before joining
- repartitioning on partitions and `id` field (`df.repartition(numPartitions, "partition_A", "partition_B", "id")`)
- sorting data by `id` before joining
  But the shuffle is still here.

I tried on both Databricks and EMR runtimes with same behaviour.

Thanks for your help